# Accessing nested array items without named elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays with none of the elements having names that is being generated. Each sub-array will have the same number of elements but the total number of sub-arrays is variable. For example,

```
var arrayAll = [
    [a,b,c,d,e,f],
    [g,h,i,j,k,l],
    [m,n,o,p,q,r]
];
```

I'd like to be able to access one element out of one array, i.e. just 'j', but am not sure of any notations to do it as I only have numbers. I've seen a few ways to access nested arrays but they all rely on the array having named items which I don't have.

Comment: What's wrong with accessing it as `arrayAll[1][3]`?

Comment: Arrays do not have named items - that is an `object` (or the inherited object part of an Array)

Comment: How did you try to access an element of the array? What information do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily access the items by number as if it were a multi-dimensional array:

```
var row = 2, // 3rd row - JS arrays are 0-indexed
    item = 3, // 4th item
    x = arrayAll[row][item];

alert(x); // "p"
```

Comment: Why not `row`/`column`?

Comment: No particular reason.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what he is looking for is a way of accessing the same column in every row. It can be done with the map function:

```
var arrayAll = [
    [a,b,c,d,e,f],
    [g,h,i,j,k,l],
    [m,n,o,p,q,r]
];

var oneColumn = arrayAll.map(function(row){ return row[3]});

// oneColumn = [d, j, p];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it dynamically at any depth, given a path as an array, and using a reducer:

```
var searchByPath = function(path, xs) {
  return path.reduce(function(acc, k) {
    return acc && acc[k]
  },xs)
}
```

For example:

```
var xs = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8]
]

// xs[1][2]
searchByPath([1,2], xs) //=> 7

// xs[3][100]
searchByPath([3,100], xs) //=> undefined
```